# Custom module for adding CSS file in admin section

Tags: theming, 8

How do I include `admin.css` in my theme so that it's loaded in the admin section (and preferably only the admin section)?

Right now when I add admin.css via the `x.libraries.yml` file, it's only loaded on the front-end.

**Update:**

So... based on your comments/answers I've created a module `admin-css`. But nothing happens. The file isn't loaded. What am I doing wrong?

Inside `admin_css.info.yml` :

```
name: Admin CSS
description: Alters the Admin CSS for better usability.
package: Custom

type: module
core: 8.x
```

Inside `admin_css.libraries.yml` :

```
admin-css:
  version: 1.x
  css:
    theme:
      css/admin.css: {}
```

Inside `admin_css.module` :

```
<?php

function admin_css_attachments(array &$attachments) {
    $is_admin = \Drupal::service('router.admin_context')->isAdminRoute();
    if ($is_admin) {
      $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'admin_css/admin-css';
      return;
    }

}
```

Comment: are you using the same themes in front-end and backend ?

Comment: No I'm not, I'm using the standard theme for back-end. But I'd like to include an admin.css in my theme, just for a few minor changes to the admin section.

Answer (score 3):

Unless you use the same theme for front and backend, that's not the right approach.

If something transcends the theme layer, e.g. you have functionality that you need to apply to two separate themes, it belongs in a module.

See [Adding stylesheets (CSS) and JavaScript (JS) to a Drupal 8 module](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/creating-custom-modules/adding-stylesheets-css-and-javascript-js-to-a-drupal-8-module) for instructions to actually accomplish that, specifically the section on *Attaching a library to all (or a subset of) pages* which contains a contrived code example:

```
function contextual_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
  if (!\Drupal::currentUser()->hasPermission('access contextual links')) {
    return;
  }

  $attachments['#attached']['library'][] = 'contextual/drupal.contextual-links';
}
```

Comment: I'm using the standard theme for backend, but I'd like to include an admin.css in my theme, just for a few minor changes to the admin section. Literally 6 lines of CSS. Is it at all possible?

Comment: Of course :) See the code example. It will need to be in a module though, for obvious reasons a theme's functionality is only loaded/invoked when it's actively being used. Executing functionality from one theme when a different theme is being used to render the page could be disastrous

Comment: I've updated the question, could you take a look at it? Thanks!

Comment: You'll need to change the logic in the attachments hook function to match your requirements, that's just a contrived example that uses a different condition. Searching "programatically determine admin page in drupal 8" should give you the answer

Comment: I've done just that (based on http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4483200/how-to-check-if-the-user-is-in-the-admin-part-of-drupal), but still no luck.

Comment: None of those answers are for Drupal 8, I don't have the exact method to hand you'll need to google it

Comment: The answer provided is for Drupal 8, at least says the answerer (and it has 30 upvotes). I'm just puzzled as how to implement it in the module. I'm obviously still doing something wrong.

Comment: Oh right, I missed the 2nd part. Yes that's the correct method, would be best to ask a new question/raise a bug report if it doesn't work

Answer (score 3):

The hook is called "hook_page_attachments"
so you have to rename your function from

```
function admin_css_attachments(array &$attachments) {
```

to

```
function admin_css_page_attachments(array &$attachments) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the Asset Injector module to add css to your admin theme: https://www.drupal.org/project/asset_injector